# C++ Template - Array Type Not Specified Error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm still working on getting my first template to work in C++. I'm creating a probability class that contains a template method for calculating the average of a given array. I have this template set up such that the array type and size are flexible.

However, I keep getting a compiler error stating that the array type is not being specified.... which has got me thinking 'Well duh'. I can't seem to fix this issue. I'm not sure whether or not I have a compiler setting misconfigured, or if I'm a missing a semicolon somewhere.

My code is posted below:

Probability Header

```
#ifndef COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H
#define COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H

 class Probability
{
    public:
        Probability(void);
        template <typename T, std::size_t N>
        void ExpectedValueDataSet(const std::array<T, N>& data)
        {
            // Do nothing (place holder)
        }

     protected:
     private:
};

#endif // COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Probability.h>

int main()
{

    std::array<float, 4> hoor = {4, 4, 1, 1};
    Probability prob;
    //prob.ExpectedValueDataSet(hoor);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put a `#include<array>` directive in the file header and, for the sake of clarity, in the `main.cpp` (even if the second one wouldn't be strictly necessary in this case).

Comment: @einpoklum Well, right, maybe I should have said *put it at the top of the file to be sure, after the macro guards*. :-)

Comment: Hah! That was a simple fix. Quick question though, what is actually happening when I say #include <array> ? I assume this is different then calling a .h file which only adds function and variable declarations correct? <array> isn't referring to a file is it?

Comment: @Teague It refers to a file that is part of an implementation of the STL. You have it somewhere on your machine (at least, if you want to compile the code above, you must have it!!).